# How to get the result of Controller.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, moq

I'm trying to integration test a controller method using ASP.Net MVC 5 using the `Controller.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction` method and using an HttpContext mock using Moq:

```
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();

request.Setup(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
request.Setup(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost"));

identity.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("admin");
user.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);

httpContext.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(user.Object);
httpContext.Setup(x => x.Items).Returns(new Dictionary<object, object>());
httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
httpContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

var controller = new MyController();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData()), controller);

controller.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(controller.ControllerContext, nameof(controller.Index));

// Do something to get either the HttpStatusCode and/or ActionResult
```

My question is:
How do I get the HttpStatusCode and/or ActionResult after InvokeAction is called?

When I debug the test, HttpStatusCode is always 0 in the mock HttpContext.

Comment: What is the result when you try `var response = controller.Index();`?

Comment: I am trying to do an integration test that takes into consideration an AuthorizationAttribute on the controller. So calling the controller method directly does not provide what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You might want to test against the application while it is running and test via an `HttpClient`. They've made this easier in `.NET Core` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0), but it is also doable in `.NET Framework`. I remember hosting a version in `IISExpress` and then firing calls via `HttpClient` (where you can read the `Http Status`), but I don't remember the details.